# Automatically checking checkbox in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Here I am trying to get the checkbox checked if every element of sensor input is 1. But somehow it's not happening. I used the same logic in another part of my code.
Here is my code.

```
from tkinter import *
sensors=[1,1,1,1,1]
def sensor_check():
    var2=IntVar()
    sensor_checkbox = Checkbutton(frame1, text="Sensors working?", variable=var2, state=DISABLED)
    sensor_checkbox.pack()

    error_list = [i+1 for i, v in enumerate(sensors) if v == 0]

    if len(error_list) == 0:
        var2.set(1)
    else:
        message = Label(frame1, text="Sensors "+error_list+" are not working properly")
        message.pack(fill="x")
mainwindow = Tk()
mainframe=Frame(mainwindow,bg="red")
mainframe.pack(fill="both",expand=True)

frame1 = Frame(mainframe)
button = Button(frame1, text="Start",command=sensor_check)
button.pack()
frame1.pack(fill="x")

mainwindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are following issues in your code:

- `var2` is a local variable which is garbage collected after exiting the function, that is why the checkbox is not checked even though all sensors are 1
- exception will be raised on `text="Sensors "+error_list+" are not working properly"` because you try to concatenate string with list

To solve the issues:

- save a reference of `var2`
- use f-string for the `text` option

```py
def sensor_check():
    var2=IntVar()
    sensor_checkbox = Checkbutton(frame1, text="Sensors working?", variable=var2, state=DISABLED)
    sensor_checkbox.pack()
    sensor_checkbox.var = var2  # save a reference of var2

    error_list = [i+1 for i, v in enumerate(sensors) if v == 0]

    if len(error_list) == 0:
        var2.set(1)
    else:
        message = Label(frame1, text=f"Sensors {error_list} are not working properly")
        message.pack(fill="x")
```